# Edit Javadoc Directly (index.html)

Tags: html, open-source, javadoc

I auto-generated my Javadoc.  All went fine.  But I want to put a header at the top of the javadoc to link to my source code.  Whenever I try to edit index.html, which is what I link to so that I can display my javadoc on my website, the javadoc vanishes and only shows what I add.  For example, if I add:

```
<body>
<p>TEST</p>
</body>
```

anywhere, then all I see is "TEST" when I link to index.html.

How can I edit my index.html to have a header at the top which links to the source code?  My index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<!--NewPage-->
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<!-- Generated by javadoc on Sun Nov 23 21:34:16 EST 2014-->
<TITLE>
Action Engine API
</TITLE>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    targetPage = "" + window.location.search;
    if (targetPage != "" && targetPage != "undefined")
        targetPage = targetPage.substring(1);
    if (targetPage.indexOf(":") != -1)
        targetPage = "undefined";
    function loadFrames() {
        if (targetPage != "" && targetPage != "undefined")
             top.classFrame.location = top.targetPage;
    }
</SCRIPT>
<NOSCRIPT>
</NOSCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<FRAMESET cols="20%,80%" title="" onLoad="top.loadFrames()">
<FRAMESET rows="30%,70%" title="" onLoad="top.loadFrames()">
<FRAME src="overview-frame.html" name="packageListFrame" title="All Packages">
<FRAME src="allclasses-frame.html" name="packageFrame" title="All classes and interfaces (except non-static nested types)">
</FRAMESET>
<FRAME src="overview-summary.html" name="classFrame" title="Package, class and interface descriptions" scrolling="yes">
<NOFRAMES>
<H2>
Frame Alert</H2>

<P>
This document is designed to be viewed using the frames feature. If you see this message, you are using a non-frame-capable web client.
<BR>
Link to<A HREF="overview-summary.html">Non-frame version.</A>
</NOFRAMES>
</FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

The generated javadoc you posted does not have a HTML `head` element, so if you add one, the browser probably just displays that.

If I understand you correctly, you want to add some text to the generated javadoc. If you want to add something to every page, you could use the `bottom` command line argument. Here's an example from the Javadoc `man` page:

```
javadoc -bottom '<a href="{@docRoot}/copyright.html">Copyright</a>'.
```

If you want to just add something to the main page, you can place it in `index.html` (or `package-info.java`) in your source folder.

Comment: Not quite getting it.  Where in index.html can I add that?  It still just removed everything except for "Copyright"

Comment: Do not edit the generated `index.html`, which will be overwritten when you run `javadoc` again. Put it in a a new `index.html` file and put that file in your source folder. `javadoc` will include that file.